# Control disappears after resetting to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, page-lifecycle

I have a usercontrol for property grid which I am adding to my page client side. It shoes up just fine, but for some reason I need to reset it to null and reinitialize it depending on a dropdown list selection. So I do :

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ctrlName = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (ctrlName == "ctl00$MainContent$ddlTIDAction")
        {
            this.ucAction = null;
            this.ucAction = new oweC.ActionControl();
        }
    }
```

and then I set the values of the control in page load and selected index change event of the dropdown. My problem is, after the event fires, the usercontrol disappears. On debugging, it seems to be getting the values correctly, but it just not renders on the page. Do I need to somehow add it again to its parent control? Does the re-initializing of a control removes it from the control hierarchy?

Comment: you should handle the dropdown's event through a delegate instead of trying to catch it in `Page_Init`.